Json Serialization Problem (Newtonsoft.Json) - Self referencing loop detected
I am trying to serialize / deserialize a FHIR json using Dotnet 8 with Newtonsoft.Json
In json, the root object is type of Resource class, it has a field called "entry" and it contains the list of different Resource objects, such as organization, patient etc.
I developed a base Resource class which has common fields and all other type of resources derive from this class, such as PatientResource, BundleResource etc.
Upon deserialization, I am checking the "resourceType" field and returning the class type accordingly as follows:

    private class ResourceConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            // We only want to process resource object
            return typeof(Resource).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
            string? resourceType = jsonObject["resourceType"]?.ToString();

            var jsonText = jsonObject.ToString();

            Resource resource;

            resource = resourceType switch
            {
                "Patient" => new PatientResource(),
                "Coverage" => new CoverageResource(),
                "Bundle" => new BundleResource(),
                _ => new Resource()
            };

            serializer.Populate(jsonObject.CreateReader(), resource);   

            return resource;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
    }


For deserialization, ReadJson works very well and gives me all child classes in accordance with the types. However upon serialization, WriteJson method throws an exception:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop detected with type 'BundleResource'. Path ''.'

My bundle class:
public class BundleResource : Resource
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public List<Entry> Entry { get; set; }
}

My entry class:
public class Entry
{
    [JsonProperty("fullUrl", Order = 0)]
    public string FullUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("resource", Order = 1)]
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}

An example class of other type resource:
public class PatientResource : Resource
{

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public List<HumanName> Names { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("telecom")]
    public List<Telecom> Telecom { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

When I used "ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore" in the JsonSerializerSettings, it returns entire json empty.
Example json structure I am working on:
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "entry": [
    {
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Bundle"
      }
    },
    {
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Patient"
      }
    },
    {
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Coverage"
      }
    }
  ]
}

How can I correctly serialize the json?

Override CanWrite and return false as shown in this answer to How to use default serialization in a custom JsonConverter and you will be able to get default serialization when writing.
